# Problems of Making Multiple Multirow Table

Tags: tables, equations, cell

I want to write a table, here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Tipe opsi barrier.}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Tipe Opsi&CBBC&\textit{Behavior}&\textit{Payoff}& \\
        \hline
        \multirow{8}{*}{Barrier \textit{Call}}& \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{Bull}}&\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textit{down-and-out} \\ (\textit{knock-out})\end{tabular}}&\multirow{2}{*}{$(S_T-K)^+\mathbbm{1}_{\biggl\{\min\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t>B\biggr\}}$}&$B\leq K$\\
        \cline{5-5}
        &&&&$B\geq K$\\
        \cline{2-5}
        &\multirow{6}{*}{}&\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textit{down-and-in}\\(\textit{knock-in})\end{tabular}}&\multirow{2}{*}{$(S_T-K)^+\mathbbm{1}_{\biggl\{\min\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t<B\biggr\}}$}&$B\leq K$\\
        \cline{5-5}
        &&&&$B\geq K$\\
        \cline{3-5}
        &&\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textit{up-and-out}\\(\textit{knock-out})\end{tabular}}&\multirow{2}{*}{$(S_T-K)^+\mathbbm{1}_{\biggl\{\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t<B\biggr\}}$}&$B\leq K$\\
        \cline{5-5}
        &&&&$B\geq K$\\
        \cline{3-5}
        &&\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textit{up-and-in}\\(\textit{knock-in})\end{tabular}}&\multirow{2}{*}{$(S_T-K)^+\mathbbm{1}_{\biggl\{\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t>B\biggr\}}$}&$B\leq K$\\
        \cline{5-5}
        &&&&$B\geq K$\\
        \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output of that code:

[image]

But, the output seems like there are mistakes. Many scripts are out of their cells. What are the problems of my code?

Comment: With your MWE the result is as expected, with it is not possible to reproduce showed result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is `\FloatBarrier` the required `placeins` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{document}
\FloatBarrier
\begin{table}
    \caption{Tipe opsi barrier.}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Tipe Opsi&CBBC&\textit{Behavior}&\textit{Payoff}& \\
        \hline
        \multirow{8}{*}{Barrier \textit{Call}}& \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{Bull}}&\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textit{down-and-out} \\ (\textit{knock-out})\end{tabular}}&\multirow{2}{*}{$(S_T-K)^+\mathbbm{1}_{\bigl\{\min\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t>B\bigr\}}$}&$B\leq K$\\
        \cline{5-5}
        &&&&$B\geq K$\\
        \cline{2-5}
        &\multirow{6}{*}{}&\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textit{down-and-in}\\(\textit{knock-in})\end{tabular}}&\multirow{2}{*}{$(S_T-K)^+\mathbbm{1}_{\bigl\{\min\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t<B\bigr\}}$}&$B\leq K$\\
        \cline{5-5}
        &&&&$B\geq K$\\
        \cline{3-5}
        &&\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textit{up-and-out}\\(\textit{knock-out})\end{tabular}}&\multirow{2}{*}{$(S_T-K)^+\mathbbm{1}_{\bigl\{\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t<B\bigr\}}$}&$B\leq K$\\
        \cline{5-5}
        &&&&$B\geq K$\\
        \cline{3-5}
        &&\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textit{up-and-in}\\(\textit{knock-in})\end{tabular}}&\multirow{2}{*}{$(S_T-K)^+\mathbbm{1}_{\bigl\{\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t>B\bigr\}}$}&$B\leq K$\\
        \cline{5-5}
        &&&&$B\geq K$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar with Sebastiano's answer, I use `\left\{...\right\}` to make fit curly bracket as below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Tipe opsi barrier.}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                Tipe Opsi&CBBC&\textit{Behavior}&\textit{Payoff}& \\
                \hline
                \multirow{8}{*}{Barrier \textit{Call}}& \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{Bull}}&\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textit{down-and-out} \\ (\textit{knock-out})\end{tabular}}&\multirow{2}{*}{$(S_T-K)^+\mathbbm{1}_{\left\{\min\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t>B\right\}}$}&$B\leq K$\\
                \cline{5-5}
                &&&&$B\geq K$\\
                \cline{2-5}
                &\multirow{6}{*}{}&\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textit{down-and-in}\\(\textit{knock-in})\end{tabular}}&\multirow{2}{*}{$(S_T-K)^+\mathbbm{1}_{\left\{\min\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t<B\right\}}$}&$B\leq K$\\
                \cline{5-5}
                &&&&$B\geq K$\\
                \cline{3-5}
                &&\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textit{up-and-out}\\(\textit{knock-out})\end{tabular}}&\multirow{2}{*}{$(S_T-K)^+\mathbbm{1}_{\left\{\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t<B\right\}}$}&$B\leq K$\\
                \cline{5-5}
                &&&&$B\geq K$\\
                \cline{3-5}
                &&\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textit{up-and-in}\\(\textit{knock-in})\end{tabular}}&\multirow{2}{*}{$(S_T-K)^+\mathbbm{1}_{\left\{\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t>B\right\}}$}&$B\leq K$\\
                \cline{5-5}
                &&&&$B\geq K$\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

And the result is

[image]